# Given a set of intervals, how to find the maximum number of intersections among them,

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Let's say you are given a set of intervals (1,5), (6,10), (3,8), (7,9). The output I expect is 3 since there are maximum 3 intervals (3,8), (6,10) and (7,9) that intersect with each other. Note that, (1,5) and (3,8) also intersect with each other but that's only 2 of them. So the answer here is going to be 3, since 3 is the maximum number of intervals that intersect with each other.

What are some efficient ways of finding it? I guess the first step would be to sort the intervals according to the starting value. Any suggestions after that?

Comment: This is a standard interview question asked and answered hundereds of times. Please try to search before posting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard solution is to process the intervals into a set of (begin,end) points. For example `(1,3)` generates `{1, begin}`, `{3, end}`. Then sort the points and scan left to right, counting `begin` as +1, `end` as -1. The max value reached by the counter is the maximum number of overlapping intervals.

This is the intermediate array generated from the example in the question:

```
[(1, 'begin'),
 (3, 'begin'),
 (5, 'end'),
 (6, 'begin'),
 (7, 'begin'),  # <--- counter reaches 3, its maximum value here.
 (8, 'end'),
 (9, 'end'), (10, 'end')]
```

There is a minor tricky point here. Does `(1,end)` go before or after `(1,begin)`? If you treat intervals as open, then it should go before - this way `(0,1)` & `(1,2)` won't be counted as intersecting. Otherwise it should go after and these intervals will count as intersecting ones.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can sort the intervals based on the start so if you have:
(1,5) , (4,8) , (2,3)

They will be sorted:
(1,5) , (2,3) , (4,8)

Then you will check the start of each interval against the highest End you found
If the start is less than the end then there's an intersection

```
int highestEnd = intervals[0].end; // The highest end would be the end of the first interval
int numOfIntersections = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < intervalsSize; i++){
    if(intervals[i].start < highestEnd)
         numOfIntersections++;
    if(intervals[i].end > highestEnd)
         highestEnd = intervals[i].end;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I think there is a flaw here. In your solution you are never resetting variable `numberOfIntersections`. Let's say after sorting it looks like this: (1,5), (3,8), (7,10), (15,20), (17,25), (23,28), (25,30). Here, your algorithm will output 7 whereas the expected answer is 4. The first 3 tuples are in intersection and the last 4 tuples are in intersection, but these 2 groups are disjoint. I think in your algorithm, whenever the condition `intervals[i].start < highestEnd` fails, we should rest the 'numberOfIntersections' to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you find this useful: (python code) - tested works correctly
Overview: I sorted according to start and found min of end times of intervals

```
def max_intersections(intervals):
max_simultaneous = 0
intersections = 0
smallest_end = intervals[0].end
intervals.sort(key=lambda x: x.start)
for i in range(len(intervals)):
    if intervals[i].start < smallest_end:
        smallest_end = min(smallest_end, intervals[i].end)
        intersections += 1
    else:
        max_simultaneous = max(max_simultaneous, intersections)
return max_simultaneous
```