# minimum number of platforms required with the given schedules of trains

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, greedy

Given arrival and departure times of all trains that reach a railway station, find the minimum number of platforms required for the railway station so that no train waits. We are given two arrays which represent arrival and departure times of trains that stop.

Examples:

Input1:

`arr[]  = {904, 946, 952, 1100, 1508, 1806}
 dep[]  = {915, 1202, 1128, 1135, 1900, 2001}`

Output1: 3

There are at-most three trains at a time 
(between 1100 to 1128)

Input2:

`arr[]  = {2200, 2300}
 dep[]  = {200, 300}`

Output2: 2

There are at-most two trains at a time 
(between 2300 to 200)

Input3:

`arr[]  = {2200, 2300, 0,}
 dep[]  = {300, 300, 300}`

Output3: 3

There are at-most three trains at a time 
(between 0 to 300)

I can find a solution in O(nLogn) complexity from geeksforgeeks, can we solve it in O(n) time complexity ?

Range of schedules is fix here between 0 to 2399, and also a train departure schedule can be next day means departure time could be less than arrival time e.g. arrival 2300 and departure 200.

We can assume that no train will stop more than 24 hours on the platform.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given a set of intervals, how to find the maximum number of intersections among them,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739542/given-a-set-of-intervals-how-to-find-the-maximum-number-of-intersections-among)

Comment: It could be similar to solve the problem but both problems are different :
Range of schedules is fix here between 0 to 2400, and also a train departure schedule can be next day means departure time could be less than arrival time e.g. arrival 2300 and departure 200.

We can assume that no train will stop more than 24 hours on the platform.

Comment: There's no definite answer if roll-over is possible and you don't know which train arrives and departs when. For example, arrivals={0010,2340}, departures={0020,2350} can be (train 1 arrives at 0010 departs at 0020, train 2 arrives at 2340 departs at 2350) or (train 1 arrives at 2340 departs at 0020, train 2 arrives at 0010 departs at 2350). You cannot restrict stop times to e.g. 12 hours or even 1 hour, because the exact same situation will be possible, just with more trains.

Comment: Each index value represent for particular train, e.g. 0 th index represents for train 1, 1 st index represents for train 2. In this given example arrivals={0010,2340}, departures={0020,2350} there is no overlap. 
For train 1 -> index 0 arrival / departure - 0010 / 0020
---------
For train 2 -> index 1 arrival / departure - 2340 / 2350

Comment: Then you can't do it in O(n) because you need to sort the data. You can do a radix or bucket sort because you only have numbers between 0 and 2359 but that's kinda cheating.

Comment: We can do it in O(n). I am working on a solution will post it once it's thoroughly tested.

Comment: @n.m. I hope now you got the idea of this problem, can you solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739542/given-a-set-of-intervals-how-to-find-the-maximum-number-of-intersections-among) problem in O(n), and do you still think this a duplicate of that.

Comment: Solving a problem based of set of input is not a cheating. If I give you problem for voting system to get winner from all the candidate, will you still use quick sort or any other sort which gave you O(nlogn) ?? or you will use counting sort.

Comment: This solution doesn't generalize. If time is given to arbitrary precision rather that to 1min, you suddenly find your method working somewhat less well. In real life I would most definitely use quicksort most of the time, because theoretical advantages of non-comparison-based methods just don't matter in practice. If I'm to submit a CS101 homework I will use whatever has requested complexity, sure.

Answer (score 3):

As we have arrival time and departure time between 1 to 2400 or 0 to 2399, we can sort time interval using Redix sort as only four times we need to use counting sort so the complexity to sort arrival and departure will be 4*n -> O(n). And then we can use merge of two sorted array to find the overlap. which will cost n+n -> O(n).
So the time complexity to solve this problem is O(n).

```
public class MinimumRequiredPlatform {

public static void main(String args[]){
    Integer[] a1 = {2200, 2300};
    Integer[] b1 = {200, 300};
    int count = findMinRequiredPlatform(a1, b1);
    Assert.isTrue(count == 2, "expected 2 but found " + count);

    Integer a2[] = {904, 946, 952, 1100, 1508, 1806};
    Integer b2[] = {915, 1202, 1128, 1135, 1900, 2001};
    count = findMinRequiredPlatform(a2, b2);
    Assert.isTrue(count == 3, "expected 3 but found " + count);

    Integer[] a3 = {2200, 2300};
    Integer[] b3 = {2300, 300};
    count = findMinRequiredPlatform(a3, b3);
    Assert.isTrue(count == 2, "expected 2 but found " + count);

    Integer[] a4 = {2200, 2300, 0};
    Integer[] b4 = {300, 0, 300};
    count = findMinRequiredPlatform(a4, b4);
    Assert.isTrue(count == 3, "expected 3 but found " + count);
}


/**
 * Time complexity (4*n + 4*n) + (n+n) -> O(n), where n is the number of trains.
 * Space complexity O(n)
 */
private static int findMinRequiredPlatform(Integer[] arr, Integer[] dep) {
    int count = 0;

    int n = arr.length;

    List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
    List<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(dep));

    for(int i = 0; i< n; i++){
        if (dep[i] < arr[i]) {
            l2.set(i, 2399);
            l1.add(0);
            l2.add(dep[i]);
        }
    }

    sort(l1);
    sort(l2);

    n = l1.size();
    int max = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(i < n || j < n) {
        if(i >= n) {
            count--;
            j++;
        }
        else if (i<n && j< n) {
            if (l1.get(i) <= l2.get(j)){
                count++;
                i++;
            } else {
                count--;
                j++;
            }
        }

        if(count > max){
            max = count;
        }
    }

    return max;
}

// Time complexity 4*n -> O(n), space complexity O(n);
private static void sort(List<Integer> a) {
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    int div = 1;
    int lastDiv;
    int count = 0;
    while(count < 4) {
        lastDiv = div;
        div *= 10;
        for (int i : a) {
            int v = (i % div)/lastDiv;
            if (map.containsKey(v)) {
                map.get(v).add(i);
            } else {
                List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(i);
                map.put(v, list);
            }
        }
        int ind = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (map.containsKey(i)) {
                List<Integer> l = map.remove(i);
                for (int v : l) {
                    a.set(ind, v);
                    ind++;
                }
            }
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

}