# Calculate maximum number of rooms occupied at once

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, schedule, greedy

On the input, we are given a number N stating how many presentations are to be given, which is followed by N rows of start and end times given in HHMM format

Example:

3

0800 0900

0830 1000

0900 1030

The code must calculate the maximum nuber of occupied rooms (one room can host only one presentation at a time, therefore expected output to the provided example is 2.

My first idea was to create a table of bools 1440 x N (number of minutes in a day by number of presentations) and fill each minute when a presentation is being held, and later go column by column and find the maximum value of presentations at a time. It works, but I'm sure it can be done faster and better. Can someone suggest how to do it in a better manner?

Comment: The only question asked is *Can someone suggest how to do it in a better manner?* Since this can be correctly answered with a completely useless, "Yes." I recommend you attempt to tighten up the question to make worthless answers harder or impossible.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm not asking **if** it can be done better, I'm asking **how**.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35743485/10548514, just adapt it to a time interval instead of an interval on real line.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple actually: we just simulate the process. First of all, it doesn't matter which presentations are going on right now. All we care about is the number of presentations happening. So we'll just have a counter which we update when a presentation starts or ends.

We could iterate over every minute for the simulation, but our counter only changes when a presentation starts or ends, so we can just make a big list of all the start and end events, sort the list by time, and iterate through the list adjusting our counter appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The way you propose needs `1440 x 3 = 4320` values. As you can tell, that's very inefficient. A better way is to store just the minutes that are actually required. To save even less values, divide the time into slots of 30 minutes.

Now use a dictionary (`std::map`) to keep a count of how many presentations are during the same time slot. For your example this gives:

```
std::map<std::string, int> slots = 
        { 
          {"0800", 1}, 
          {"0830", 2}, 
          {"0900", 2}, 
          {"0930", 2},
          {"1000", 1}, 
          {"1030", 1},
        }
```

I'll let you figure out how to implement this.